# Replace category titles inside RSS feed

Tags: categories, filters, hooks, rss, feed

I need to replace titles in `<category> ... </ category>` tag inside the default RSS feed (mywebsite.com/feed/).

Of course, it would be more convenient to just rename the categories, but for a number of reasons I can't do that.

This is the example of what I need:

- Categories "**Apples**" and "**Pears**" inside the RSS feed should be replaced with "**Fruits**".
- Categories "**Raspberry**" and "**Strawberry**" inside the RSS feed should be replaced with "**Berries**".

I am very bad at functions and filters yet. I would be very grateful to those who help.

**EDIT:** that's what I managed to do to make it work with `get_post_type()`

```
function changeRSStitles($content) {
if (get_post_type($post) == 'post') {
    $content = '<category>Fruits</category>';
}else {
    $content = $content;
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_category_rss', 'changeRSStitles');
```

But I couldn't get it to work with `get_the_category()`

```
function changeRSStitles($content) {
if (get_the_category($id) == '1') {
    $content = '<category>Fruits</category>';
}else {
    $content = $content;
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_category_rss', 'changeRSStitles');
```

Just nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your content vs Category?  meaning is "Apples, Pears, Raspberry, Strawberry" is that your content? and (fruits, berries) are categories?

Comment: Thank you for responding, NickFMC.

"Apples, Pears, Raspberry, Strawberry" are a list of categories that are currently on my website. When I publish a new post, I can choose one or several of them.

If I write an article about apples, I will select the category "Apples" for that post. In the RSS feed, the category tag for this post will look like this: `<category>Apples</category>`.

What I need now, is to adjust everything in such a way that the content of the `<category>` tag is replaced from `<category>Apples</category>` to `<category>Fruits</category>`. But only in the RSS feed.

Comment: I managed to do something, but not quite what was needed. I edited my question above.